# Add event listener for every event in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, event-handling

Is there any way in Actionscript 3 to add an event listener for any event, in order to do something like trace it?  There is a very complicated library that I'm trying to figure out and going through and adding an event listener for every constant in the file would take up more lines of script than the rest of the project.

Comment: May be this will help you: http://www.granitedataservices.com/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.reflection.html

Comment: That looks like it is for getting and setting properties.  I'd also rather not have to include an external library for what I'm doing but if I have to I'm okay with that (this is just for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to prepare the file with the constants first, embed it into the project, get array of strings out of it and add a listener per string, like this:

```
[Embed(source = 'yourFile.txt', mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
public static const EmbeddedFile:Class; // name accordingly
....
var ba:ByteArray=new EmbeddedFile();
var a:Array = ba.toString.split('\n');
for each (var e:String in a) addEventListener(e,yourFunction);
...
function yourFunction(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.type);
    trace(flash.utils.describeType(e));
    // more if you like
}
```

Comment: So, in the yourFile.txt I should have something like this? `event1(newline)event2(newline)event3`

Comment: I don't think I can find all of the events in this library documented, I would rather have something that adds for all events, as I asked for in the question

Comment: There's no thing like adding a listener to listen to "all events", you can only listen to a certain type of events. Pity.